# Handling multi-stage input language in UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, nsattributedstring, cjk

I have a regular `UITextField` in my view controller:

`@IBOutlet private weak var textField: UITextField!`

This text field has a delegate set to it, as well as an event listener. Whenever a text value gets changed, the method `textFieldDidChange` gets called.

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)),
                             for: .editingChanged)
}
```

Inside the `textFieldDidChange` method, I call a view model method that takes the text field's text, formats it, and returns a value:

```
@objc private func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
        textField.attributedText = viewModel.standardAttributedText(text: textField.text)
}
```

---

The problem is that this breaks the multi-stage input for languages such as Japanese, because I am consistently setting the text on every change, and am not waiting for input to finish.

**Example**: `し` + `゛` = `し`

Should have been `じ`

---

To give a bit of context - the text field has two 'attributed' states, highlighted and regular. The highlighted state can happen at any time, and the regular state gets applied whenever the text is changed.

**Question**: how can I take the multi-stage input into consideration and wait for it to finish, or set text field's text attributes so that no issues are caused?

All help immensely appreciated, it's my first time facing a challenge with multi-stage input languages!